# after formating my laptop, my Django projects doesn't work

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

Before I format my laptop, I cut & paste my Django project (folder that include mysite and myvenv folders) to another partition. It was built on python 2.7 and used virtual environment and Django 1.7.

Now I have python 3.4, and after activating virtual environment and run:

$ python manage.py makemigrations

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

So I tried and installed python2.7 but still get the same error.

Is there a way to correct what happend to my project and if not I need your advice for best practise on how can I move Django project without break it?

- In my Django project I followed the official tutorial on djangoproject.com
- This is my first question on stackoverflow

Comment: Do you have Django installed after formatting?

Comment: you need to install Django.

Comment: Hello ForceBru :)
For this project I didn't installed Django because I thought it installed in the virtual environment!

Comment: Thanks ForceBru and Salman Wahed. After deleting the current virtualenv folder and create new one and install Django, it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I revoke my answer. I no longer want to support this site.

Comment: I did exactly as you said except the requirements.txt file because in djangoproject.com tutorial they didn't mention it, and it worked :)

Thank you very much "Welenofsky"

Comment: No problem. The requirements.txt file is just a list of the installed libraries that you install with pip. You can list the files that you have installed in your environment with pip freeze and save those to a file, by convention requirements.txt. Then when you move your project you can install the dependencies by using pip install -r requirements.txt instead of copying the environment. [Here is more information from the pip documentation.](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#requirements-files)

Comment: I created the requirements.txt file now using: pip freeze > requirements.txt after activating the virtual env.

So next time, I should move (my project folder and requirements.txt file) only and then create new virtual env. and run: pip install -r requirements.txt

Thank you

Comment: Yes, that is the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that your manage.py is not configured properly. The first line must define the Python exec to run the script, and not another location like `/user/bin/python`. If it is set to `/user/bin/python` you will almost certainly have certain packages missing. Ensure that the path you specify is to your virtualenv python location.

Comment: Hello Elizion,

I've been trying your answer for hours :) but I wasn't able to solve the problem.

What I have in manage.py is: #!/usr/bin/env python

my project works on python2.7 which is located in /usr/bin/

I am intrested in your answer because you're saying that after formating my laptop, I don't need to delete my old virtual env.

Even thought it's not problem to delete myvenv and create a new one but I want to know if there's a way and also I want to understand how the (#!/usr/bin/env python) line works.

Thank you